# The same program written in Jupyter notebook with Pyhon 3.7 doesn't work somewhere else

Tags: python, jupyter

Imagine the situation like below. There must be simple explanation.

I have a program written in Jupyter notebook and use Python 3.7. There is no errors while executing the program and works on two PC computers. As I remember there where just only Python 3.7 (and adds like matplotlib etc. all what is needed).

[image]

Then on the others computers where is Python 3.8 the same programs gives me an error. Why?

[image]

I took another two PC removed all Python installation and install 3.7 3.8 3.9 3.10 Python (tried every of them) and I can't execute the programs without error. Why is like that? All extensions like matplotlib, numpy , scipy which is needed every time are install in proper way by pip etc...Path in Windows are always correct.

It seems to me that on those two computer where program work fine was only Python 3.7 (but I am not sure in 100% that there hadn't been installed previous version of the Python) the programs works. Any other installation or refreshment of the Python  makes that teh program gives me errors.

The only one what I should to do is 100% reset Windows and do fresh and the newest one Python instillation (Jupyther etc.) and check whether the error exist or not. But I would like to know what makes the problem and not to refresh all my Windows installation every time.

The problem is even more interesting when I am taking the same program
and put them to the virtual Jupyther using the Internet and browser they always work fine without any errors and there is for sure the news Python engine I guess not 3.7.

Comment: Can you add your code as code not images?

Comment: compare the values of `matplotlib.__version__` variable on the computers where it works and doesn't work... the `adjustable`  argument to axis may have been added or removed in more recent versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to execute "pip freeze" or "conda list" on these computers (with Ananconda Powershell for ex.) to verify that all the libraries' versions you are using are the same?

Looking at the error on the screenshot, I would bet that the problem does not come from your Python version but more from a higher version on matplotlib installed on the first two PCs, which makes that the third one (with potentially an older version of matplotlib) does not support the arguments given.

Just try executing:

```
(base) PS C:\XXX\Python> conda list matplotlib
```

and should get the version of matplotlib installed on each PC, like this:

```
# packages in environment at C:\XXX\Miniconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
matplotlib                3.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib-inline         0.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
```

If they are different, this might be where the issue comes from.

Comment: Thank you. For sure you are right and I thought abut this that something must left or is mixing (older the newest version etc). But I install just only the higher libraries not mixing with older one lie 3.6. I would be said that the higher libraries like 3.10 wouldn't be compatible withe the 3.7. I believe there are and like I said when I put the same program to the Jupyter lab via browser it works fine. I did pip freeze and there a list appeared and I am not sure how to use it to take some information. conda list I just have read about this looking for solution and I am not skilled enough.

Comment: I have added some instructions on how to use conda list in my original post to make it clearer.

Comment: To follow on @Pierre-LouisBescond 's answer, controlling the environment is a major component of reproducibility. I don't know what 'virtual Jupyter' you are using but for down the road, MyBinder.org let's you use repositories, such as those Github to control what is in the launched remote session. For example, see [here](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/sample_repos.html#conda-environment-with-environment-yml). And as MB-F comments, the module code & recommended best-approaches change, and so sometimes it's easier to adapt the code to where you are running it presently.

Comment: Continuing... In other words, you've found a common situation in the open source community. It is almost to be expected that the same code written one place doesn't work in another out of the gate. Usually though you can sort it out with a little effort. Here, it may be better to focus on updating your plot code. when you find what has the most current versions.

Comment: Yes. It seems that I have just lent due to you where was my problem. I use the source program base on some code from 2015 and it is what you said ...the code doesn't work every were. I was sure that if I have well working code from 2015 it should be compatible with Python 2.8 2.10 etc. other words the newest version of Python can compile what was written in the past because this is idea of the Python 3.x. They used just Python 3.0 and the code works up to 3.7. From 3.8 and higher the code should be correcter from pyplot.axis('scaled', adjustable='box') to this pyplot.axis('scaled') Thank you.

Comment: ..and I of course used mybinder.org Jupyther lab to check the code but I was sure the use the news one version today it would be 3.10 but there is 3.0 engine I see that the code just worked and it fooled me because I was sure that if I had installed 3.10 on my PC (the newest one to be up to date with Python) all my old codes would have worked and I can just improve my code with sth new which we can fin in 3.10. The true is that in any case 3.9 to 3.10 there sth can be also improve in packages too like in matplotlib was and the code may not work like before. It shouldn't be like that but it is.

Comment: Finally I was very lucky that I had take the code from 2015 and had Python 3.7 and the programs just worked fine. If I had had Python 2.9 I would be looking at why there is some errors now and program doesn't work. Tanks.